# How can I learn German in one week?

Tags: learning, standard-german

How can I learn German in one week?

If there is way to listen and talk that will be better.

Comment: For which purpose would you need your German basics after a one-week crash course?

Comment: I can not understand the second sentence... please someone tell me I'm not dumb..

Comment: Well, people say german is a very difficult language to learn. I'll say they're right, as I'm _still_ learning it, despite it being my native tongue. So the simple answer to this question is: You can't.

Comment: **Nobody** can learn a language in one week.

Comment: @Em1 there was this autistic guy, who learned Finnnish in ten days...

Comment: No you cannot. Not in a week, not in a month and probably not in a year.

Comment: Gib besser auf. Die Grammatik und Aussprache wird dich umhauen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to learn some formulas as Guten Tag, Auf Wiedersehen, Danke, Bitte, Ja, Nein,
and so on, I think you can do it in one week. Whether you can call this "to learn German"
is another question.

There are books available that promise "Learn German/English in thirty hours" - that is throwing sand in your eyes. They mean thirty lessons of German/English and contain nothing but a basic survey of the basic grammar of a language and perhaps a vocabulary of 500 to 1000 words.

Don't fool yourself. The study of a foreign language is always a study of several years, no matter how many people tell you you can learn German in a week. They want to sell you something. And they promise you the moon.

And studying a foreign language has its price. You need good tools for learning a language.
A dictionary for beginners, a bigger dictionary, a good grammar for beginners, course books,
audio material, texts for beginners - all that has its cost. And when you engage a private teacher, he has his price too. Good things cost money.

And forget "Crash Courses". What you learn in the one week of a crash course you have forgotten in the next week. Some people think learning a language is another person that fills the language in their mind. No, learning a foreign language is a technique you have to learn for yourself and most people who learn a foreign language know nothing about the technique of learning a language. It is an active thing, not a passive thing that others do for you.

Comment: I haven't better to say than you have said. Very good words.

Comment: actually after this i have to say shame on me :) but can recommend for me some good book or audio lessons and thanks